# Selecting rows after a row based on the WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

For example let's say I have the table test, with only 1 property.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    alphabet VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

+----------+
| alphabet |
+----------+
| a        |
| b        |
| c        |
| d        |
| e        |
+----------+
```

I only want to show a table of rows after b, so I would do something like.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE alphabet="b"
```

But that would give me the row b only, so I would use the LIMIT command to try to show other rows. I don't know how to do that though with LIMIT, as LIMIT requires an id and my table does not have an id or indicator of any kind, how do I show a table of.

```
+----------+
| alphabet |
+----------+
| c        |
| d        |
| e        |
+----------+
```

Comment: In SQL *after* is defined only for a given order. How is your table ordered?

Comment: It's not in any given order, let's say it's a table of names of people that walks into a store everyday, meaning it's continuously updated.

So if 10 people walk into the store the first day with the last person named "Bob" and 10 people walk into the store the second day with the first person named "Tim", and I only want to pull the 10 people on the second day, how would I do that?

Comment: In such case they will be ordered by another field, such as `datetime` they entered a store.

Comment: Let's say there's only 1 column, "customers", and nothing else.

Comment: Then if you want to have a consistent order it needs to be based on that single column. Alternatively, you can have a random order.  In either vase order **should be** defined - no if's or but's.

Comment: Would [**What is the default order of records for a SELECT statement in MySQL?**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) post on dba site clarify the situation for you?

Comment: I do want to have an order, but the problem given to me only has this.

    CREATE TABLE shop (
 customers VARCHAR NOT NULL
    );

Where customers will have the form (name.gender)

And it wants me to update another table with the number of males/females that walk into the store every day.

Comment: Where did you get such assignment from?  Book, tutorial, etc...?

Comment: It's just an assignment given to me by someone as a challenge, and they told me to "make any assumptions I want to"

Comment: OK. Then assume that the process of count calculation would run once nightly and that the `shop` table will be truncated right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your table schema is not good as it should always have a unique id to use (look into normalizing your table). but this does provide the result you are asking for.. its not a good way to do this though as it can sometimes return a different result.

**SETUP:**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    `alphabet` VARCHAR(55)
);

insert into customers (`alphabet`)
values
('bill'),
('bob'),
('harry'),
('abe'),
('ben'),
('ashley'),
('cal'),
('fes'),
('parker'),
('gabe'),
('barry'),
('ruben'),
('sam'),
('john'),
('tim');
```

**QUERY:**

run the first query that sets a user-defined-variable and then run the second one

```
SET @QUERY := (
SELECT counter FROM(
SELECT @A := @A + 1 counter, alphabet FROM customers
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := 0) t
) temp 
WHERE alphabet = 'ashley');

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT @A := @A + 1 counter, alphabet FROM customers
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := 0) t
) AS temp
WHERE counter > @QUERY;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE alphabet > 'b'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY alphabet
LIMIT 2, 100
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da137/3)

Comment: That may have been a bad example. Let's say the table is not in order, but a large set of unique names that are not in any given order, e.g. [bob, tim, frank, joe, ashley, cindy, ...] and that this order can't be changed. If I want to pull everything after ashley how would I do it?

Comment: After Ashley alphabetically wise?

Comment: @user3830906 - There is **no such thing** as "*not in any given order*" in SQL.

Comment: @PM77-1: If you don't define an order you can't predict the order in your select.

Comment: Just the entire rest of the table after Ashley regardless of alphabet.

Comment: @user3830906: But if you don't define an order then the result order may be different each time you execute your select. Either you have an order or you don't. SQL does not have a default order.

Comment: I agree and it was my point exactly.  How can we now explain it to OP?

Comment: @user3830906: Think about how a SQL engine works. If you tell the DB to return the result in a specific order then it will, which costs performance. If you don't define an order then the DB will just grab the records as fast as possible no matter in which order.

Comment: Ok I get that, but my problem doesn't permit or allow for a given order. Is there an internal system that keeps track of inserts in mysql?

Comment: @user3830906: No, there is not.

Comment: @user3830906: How do **you** know the correct order of the records?

Comment: You have a good point, I just assumed that the select will always show the entries in the order it was entered if not given a condition.

Comment: @user3830906: I can be returned in that order but you can't **rely** on that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

You can also apply most operators to the text field.

```
Select * from test where alphabet > 'b'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE alphabet NOT IN ('b');
```

Comment: Sure, Select everything but the letter b from table.

Comment: Edit your post and include that information. Also format it and fix the capitalization while you're at it, and your answer would be very helpful.